# Is there a way to invert the colors of the images only in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, accessibility

I've inverted the colors for everything on my Mac, which makes it much easier to read text. The only downside is the images. It would be nice if there were a way to invert only the pictures in Chrome. I've found extensions that reverse everything, but I've not seen a way to reverse images.

So to be clear, I've already inverted everything, so by inverting the images they will be reverted back.

It would be great to be able to invert Videos too, but I figure I can tackle that later. Less of a big deal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a hack but since you tagged this as `Chrome` we are able to use `-webkit-filter` to invert images with CSS.

Maybe make an extension out of that or use a bookmarklet (like below) on each page.

```
javascript:var%20imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){imgs[i].setAttribute("style","-webkit-filter:invert(100%)");};
```

**Edit 1**: I found [Reluminate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reluminate/ejfgkpndiembgmnikjbdkbiiobdmcgji), a chrome extention that does what you want. It's a less hacky solution.

**Edit 2**: Vendor prefixes (i.e `webkit-`) are not needed since [CSS filters are pretty standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert()#browser_compatibility) now.

Comment: I'm fine with a hack. That seems to work for some images. I'm guessing it doesn't change the images that are part of the style.

Comment: I made one that inverts YouTube videos too:

    javascript:var vids=document.getElementsByTagName("video");for(i=0;i<vids.length;i++){vids[i].setAttribute("style","-webkit-filter:invert(100%)");};

Comment: Yes, the invert filter is not applied to background images and such, just <img> elements. 
It was meant as a demo but you could target background-images and (html5) video elements as well.

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I am looking for:)

Answer (score 0):

Inverter for Nocturne (available at the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inverter-for-nocturne/glhdmahaicellakggkjdgngimcphbfjd?hl=en)) was specifically designed to "undo" the inversion on both images and YouTube videos when screen is inverted via, for example,

- Mac Nocturne
- Windows NegativeScreen
- Windows Powerstrip (Inverted Gamma Ramp)

I find it works well in this capacity; the only (quite large) downside is that you lose colour, and all images are black and white.
Apart from this it carries out the task well.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just/at least a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I hope I am not too late, but I have made an extension that might help you which only inverts images that you want, I am posting link of git repository incase anyone wants to download chrome extension:

https://github.com/simplekind/Invert-Image-Chrome-Extension

Steps to download this extension is mentioned in the README of repo itself.
I hope it would be useful :)